# Is it possible to select HTML elements which appear anywhere after another HTML element using pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, xhtml, pseudo-class

Is it possible to select any/all `<h1>` element(s) which appear(s) after an `<h2>` element using pure CSS?

I have combed through pages of documentation for all of the CSS selectors and pseudo-classes and am unable to determine if it's possible to select certain elements which appear AFTER certain elements, both within the same branch and within a different branch of the HTML markup.

It seems as though the selectors and pseudo-classes are designed to only locate elements which are:

- Siblings
- Children
- Descendants

I am in need of finding additional relationships:

- Nieces
- Nephews
- Cousins
- Third cousins twice removed
- Granduncles
- Etc

Which are logically AFTER a certain element in the tree. I never know:

- The exact relationship
- How many there will be of the elements I desire to select.

```html
Example 1 - Niece
<div>
  <h2>2</h2>
  <div>
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
</div>

Example 2 - Cousin
<div>
  <div>
    <h2>2</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
</div>

Example 3 - Granduncle
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h2>2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>1</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: There should never be a `<h1>` after a `<h2>`, which is probably what you want to highlight, right? Neither should there be several `<h1>`, of course.

Comment: Otherwise, no, there is no selector as far as I know that would allow this.

Comment: @Andy, yes to your question about the motives for selecting/highlighting. Thanks for giving some confirmation I'm not totally dense and unable to come up with the syntax I'm looking for. I may have to try and do this another way (Javascript is not an option) but maybe someone will chime in with some new information we're overlooking.

Comment: I remember that someone created a stylesheet that would highlight accessibility errors and warnings only based on CSS. Right now I can find [Checka11y](https://github.com/jackdomleo7/Checka11y.css). Maybe you’ll find some orientation there?

Comment: No it’s not possible in the examples you have given.

Comment: Only Neice is possible in majority of browsers. Cousin and Granduncle will require [`:has` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) [available in Safari and soon Chrome](https://caniuse.com/?search=has)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to select any/all  element(s) which appear(s) after an  element using pure CSS?

Pure CSS? Yes
Browser support? Only [Safari and newer versions of Chrome](https://caniuse.com/?search=has)

Using the [`:has()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) we can check descendants without targeting them directly:

```css
:root {
  --good-browser-support: skyblue;
  --emerging-browser-support: coral;
}

.example :has(h2)+ :is(h1, * h1) {
  /* Ancestor to sibling */
  color: var(--emerging-browser-support);
}

.example :has(h2)+* h1 {
  /* Ancestor to descendant */
  color: var(--emerging-browser-support);
}

.example h2+h1 {
  /* Subsequent siblings */
  color: var(--good-browser-support);
}

.example h2+* h1 {
  /* Nieces */
  color: var(--good-browser-support);
}
```

```html
Example 1 - Niece
<div class="example">
  <h2>2</h2>
  <div>
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
</div>
Example 2 - Cousin
<div class="example">
  <div>
    <h2>2</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
</div>
Example 3 - Granduncle
<div class="example">
  <div>
    <div>
      <h2>2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>1</h1>
</div>
Example 4 - Uncle
<div class="example">
  <div>
    <h2>2</h2>
  </div>
  <h1>1</h1>
</div>
Example 5 - Non-target: Prior Siblings
<div class="example">
  <h1>1</h1>
  <h2>2</h2>
</div>
Example 6 - Subsequent Siblings
<div class="example">
  <h2>2</h2>
  <h1>1</h1>
</div>
Example 7 - Non-target: Prior Niece
<div class="example">
  <div>
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
  <h2>2</h2>
</div>
Example 5 - Non-target: Prior Siblings shared parent
<div class="example">
  <div>
    <h1>1</h1>
    <h2>2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Condensed version:

```css
:is(.example :has(h2)+ :is(h1, * h1), .example :has(h2)+* h1, .example h2 + h1, .example h2 + * h1) {
  color: magenta;
}
```

```html
Example 1 - Niece
<div class="example">
  <h2>2</h2>
  <div>
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
</div>
Example 2 - Cousin
<div class="example">
  <div>
    <h2>2</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
</div>
Example 3 - Granduncle
<div class="example">
  <div>
    <div>
      <h2>2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>1</h1>
</div>
Example 4 - Uncle
<div class="example">
  <div>
    <h2>2</h2>
  </div>
  <h1>1</h1>
</div>
Example 5 - Non-target: Prior Siblings
<div class="example">
  <h1>1</h1>
  <h2>2</h2>
</div>
Example 6 - Subsequent Siblings
<div class="example">
  <h2>2</h2>
  <h1>1</h1>
</div>
Example 7 - Non-target: Prior Niece
<div class="example">
  <div>
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
  <h2>2</h2>
</div>
Example 5 - Non-target: Prior Siblings shared parent
<div class="example">
  <div>
    <h1>1</h1>
    <h2>2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you target only a subsequent nth-cousin, where n is arbitrary?

Comment: @Alohci should be able to, I don't think that would fit OP's question though. If you think it would fit this question add the example to my list and I'll fix up the selector if needed. If you don't think it would be a good fit I'd be happy to answer a question of your own